# How do I get my JavaScript to iterate onto a new line in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got two files: grocery.js and grocery.html.

I've created an array in JavaScript that contains several "grocery list item" objects. Currently, each item is replacing the prior item each time it iterates. How do I fix the code so it prints each shopping item on a new line in my web browser?

I've tried several combinations of "\n" and "
".

Grocery.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Grocery List</title></head>
    <body>
        <script src="grocery.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Grocery.js

```
var Grocery = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Grocery(name, quantity, groceryType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.groceryType = groceryType;
    }
    return Grocery;
}());
function listPrinter(listItems) {
    return listItems.groceryType + ": " + listItems.name + " - " + listItems.quantity;
}

var item_1 = new Grocery("Apples", "14", "Fruit");
var item_2 = new Grocery("Cookies", "3", "Dessert");
var item_3 = new Grocery("Broccoli", "5", "Vegetable");

var groceryList = [item_1, item_2, item_3];

for (var _i = 0, groceryList_1 = groceryList; _i < groceryList_1.length; _i++) {
    var item = groceryList_1[_i];
    document.body.textContent = listPrinter(item);
}
```

Comment: You need to add a `<br>` tag to each item for a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list. Use the appropriate HTML element, an ordered list (`ul`) with list items (`li`). List list item (`li`) is a block element by default so each one will be on a new "Line".

<strike>We are going to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make our life easy</strike>

After Brad's perfectly valid comments we are going to use a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to manage our list items.

```js
function Grocery(name, quantity, groceryType) {
  this.name = name;
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.groceryType = groceryType;
}


var item_1 = new Grocery("Apples", "14", "Fruit");
var item_2 = new Grocery("Cookies", "3", "Dessert");
var item_3 = new Grocery("Broccoli", "5", "Vegetable");

var groceryList = [item_1, item_2, item_3];
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
//Iterate the array
groceryList.forEach(function(item) {
  //Create a list item
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  //Set boilerplate inner html
  li.innerHTML = "<span class='item'></span> - <span class='quantity'></span><span class='category'></span>"
  //Add it to our fragment
  fragment.appendChild(li);
  //Update the values
  li.querySelector(".item").innerText = item.name;
  li.querySelector(".quantity").innerText = item.quantity;
  li.querySelector(".category").innerText = item.groceryType;
  
  //For fun lets add a class to list item based on type
  li.classList.add(item.groceryType);
  
});

//Update the list element once
document.getElementById("groceryList").appendChild(fragment)
```

```css
#groceryList {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#groceryList li {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

.item {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.category {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #CCC;
  text-align: right;
}

.Fruit {background-color: #FEE;}
.Vegetable {background-color: #EFE;}
.Dessert {background-color: #FFE;}
```

```html
<ul id="groceryList"></ul>
```

By using a semantic element like a list you can style differently as required using CSS. You loose this capability with `<br>`. The only thing changed below is the CSS:

```js
function Grocery(name, quantity, groceryType) {
  this.name = name;
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.groceryType = groceryType;
}


var item_1 = new Grocery("Apples", "14", "Fruit");
var item_2 = new Grocery("Cookies", "3", "Dessert");
var item_3 = new Grocery("Broccoli", "5", "Vegetable");

var groceryList = [item_1, item_2, item_3];
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
//Iterate the array
groceryList.forEach(function(item) {
  //Create a list item
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  //Set blank inner html
  li.innerHTML = "<span class='item'></span> - <span class='quantity'></span><span class='category'></span>"
  //Add it to our fragment
  fragment.appendChild(li);
  //Update the values
  li.querySelector(".item").innerText = item.name;
  li.querySelector(".quantity").innerText = item.quantity;
  li.querySelector(".category").innerText = item.groceryType;

  //For fun lets add a class to list item based on type
  li.classList.add(item.groceryType);

});

//Update the list element once
document.getElementById("groceryList").appendChild(fragment)
```

```css
#groceryList {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#groceryList li {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

#groceryList li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 2px;
}

.item {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.category {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #CCC;
}

.Fruit:before {
  content: '';
}

.Vegetable:before {
  content: '';
}

.Dessert:before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul id="groceryList"></ul>
```

Comment: I appreciate the thoroughness of this answer, but it's completely inappropriate to use a template literal to shove text into the context of HTML.  It would need to be escaped properly, and the easiest/best way to do that would be to simply set the text content of the element anyway.  Please don't teach people that this is the way to do HTML templating... this opens them up to security issues, among other problems.

Comment: @Brad - this is the way I've always done it (doesn't mean it's right). Any quick resource you can point me at to improve my knowledge here? Mainly along the lines of "how templating should be done".

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of possible directions.  Let me see if I can explain the gist.  Imagine if the name of that grocery item is the literal text `<buy snacks>`.  That gets inserted into the HTML, and now the entire page is broken because the browser thinks we want a tag called `<buy>` with a property of `snacks`.  Or, more maliciously, someone has the username of `<script src="https://evil-server.example.com/something-evil.js">` and they appear in the user list on the site.  Now, that script has full control over everything for all users.

Comment: The way to fix this is to set the `innerText` properties of elements after you create them.  The browser then knows that this arbitrary text is... text, not script.  And then it doesn't matter what the text is, it's safe.

Comment: Now, it can be quite tedious to go around setting `innerText` everywhere.  And for that, there are hundreds of frameworks and template engines.  For anything I need to update often, or when I need a more complex application, I like to use Riot.js.  For one-off updating, I usually use EJS.

Comment: @Brad thanks. Makes perfect sense, and is one of those things that is obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

To add the current item to the existing items in innerText use `+=` and not `=` which will replace the current content.

To get line breaks you'll have to use HTML, so change innerText to innerHTML, and add `<br>` to the string of each item.

```js
function Grocery(name, quantity, groceryType) {
  this.name = name;
  this.quantity = quantity;
  this.groceryType = groceryType;
}

function listPrinter(listItem) {
  return listItem.groceryType + ": " + listItem.name + " - " + listItem.quantity + '<br>';
}

var item_1 = new Grocery("Apples", "14", "Fruit");
var item_2 = new Grocery("Cookies", "3", "Dessert");
var item_3 = new Grocery("Broccoli", "5", "Vegetable");

var groceryList = [item_1, item_2, item_3];

for (var _i = 0, groceryList_1 = groceryList; _i < groceryList_1.length; _i++) {
  var item = groceryList_1[_i];
  document.body.innerHTML += listPrinter(item); // note the +=
}
```